# JS: how to listen for function execution?

Tags: javascript, dom, listener

I need to implement a listener which will perform a certain action if FunctionA is called on the page at any time (during or after page load).

Or in other words I need to listen for an execution of FunctionA.

How to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you change the content of functionA?

Comment: What does functionA do?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change/modify the content of FunctionA.

Comment: I have seen a tag management solution which allows to bind a tag to a function call; is if a function is called on Page A the tag gets fired. How is that achieved? That's what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a self-wrapping function the following way.

```
var _ = functionA; // This variable needs to be always available to functionA
functionA = function(arg1, arg2) {
    _(arg1, arg2);
    alert("functionA was caled!");
}
```

Change the alert part to you event

This way everytime anyone calls this function you get notified.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a Function at the end/start of your FunctionA:

```
   function FunctionA(){

       /* Your method implementation here */

       FunctionB();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Cristian, but I have no access to FunctionA. I need to implement a DOM listener.

Comment: Oups, well, could you know when does the FunctionA is called?
As far as I know, there is not a 'functionExecutionListener'.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure function A has synchronous code you can wrap it in a function of yours and track its execution that way

```
function _A(){
  A.call(undefined, ...arguments);
  // A has finished execution
}
```

if the code is asynchronous then the issue is more complicated